# Put variable inside image url that is already contained in array

Tags: php, wordpress

i have the code

```
array( "name" => "Services Widget Description",
       "desc" => "Max 500 character(Use new line for new Point)",
       "std"=>"<ul>
                  <li>
             Rebum corrumliit neglegentur sit at,
           <img class='line22' width='243' height='2' alt='text line' src='images/text-line.jpg'>
        </li>
               </ul>"
),
```

URL is a variable which contains `http://localhost/Junk` , i want to use this variable inside src, i have tried like this

```
array( "name" => "Services Widget Description",
       "desc" => "Max 500 character(Use new line for new Point)",
       "std"=>"<ul>
                  <li>
             Rebum corrumliit neglegentur sit at,
           <img class='line22' width='243' height='2' alt='text line' src=URL.'images/text-line.jpg'>
        </li>
               </ul>"
),
```

but no use, please guide how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL` is a `CONSTANT` not a variable.

Integrate `URL` in code `".URL."`

```
array( "name" => "Services Widget Description",
       "desc" => "Max 500 character(Use new line for new Point)",
       "std"=>"<ul>
                  <li>
                      Rebum corrumliit neglegentur sit at,
                      <img class='line22' width='243' height='2' alt='text line' src='".URL."images/text-line.jpg'>
                  </li>
               </ul>"
),
```

Comment: Thanx dear , it works, i always face difficulty with doing such nesting, can you refer where i can read syntax for integrating variables